# Field: version.deployment_uri Error: The total size of files in gs://my-bucket/ml/ is x bytes, which exceeds the allowed maximum of 1073741824 bytes

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

When trying to create a new version in the google cloud console, I get an error like,

Field: version.deployment_uri Error: The total size of files in gs://my-bucket/ml/ is 2150116163 bytes, which exceeds the allowed maximum of 1073741824 bytes.

My model is an RNN model.  I believe the embed sequence, vocab size, is likely the cause of the large model.

Is there a quota setting that can be adjusted for larger models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that limit is not adjustable at this time, although it may be in the future.

Are you comfortable sharing how large your model is? That information is valuable for us for planning purposes.

In the meantime, you will need to adjust the vocab and embedding sizes or otherwise reduce the size of the model.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question with the exact model size. One after thought I had is that the embed sequence vocab size represents the, "Integer number of symbols in vocabulary". In my case that seems to be `max(text.ByteProcessor(max_document_length=MAX_DOCUMENT_LENG‌​TH).fit_transform(['‌​word1', 'word2'])) + 1`.  Where before I was setting vocab_size to the number of examples I have.  This made my model size less than 1MB.

Comment: @rhaertel80 we're also hitting this constraint trying to deploy a CNN trained on 3d image data of approx. 650 Mb, the model size limit now seems to be 250 Mb. We would be really happy if it was somehow possible to test deploying this model in gcloud ml.

Comment: Very soon we will have the ability to adjust the quota on a per-project basis. Please contact cloudml-feedback@google.com with your project name.